# change or move text position in a PDF file

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, pdf

Via a .net application, I want to modify a pdf document by moving the first line or the first word little space down.

is there any library that can help me to change some text position on the pdf document programmatically?

i want to change the y position of a text object on the pdf, this operation will be done for many files, and i don't want to use any intermediate process like converting to svg or word, i want a direct modification to the pdf file.

i have checked some libraries like PdfSharp , iTextSharp , PDFLibNet , Amyuni, pdfclown and i didn't find a solution for this problem.

Comment: You need to provide more detail to allow us to answer your question. For example how are you creating the pdf, are you using iTextSharp? Also consider tagging the question with the language you are using e.g. C# or VB.NET

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You might want to better describe what you're doing and where you're stuck. Are you generating a new PDF file? Or do you want to modify an existing one? Are you using a specific PDF library?

Comment: You say you want to move a paragraph. PDF does not know a paragraph. Thus, please describe accurately what PDF objects you want to move.

Comment: I want to move only some words, words on the first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

over than one month of researching for a solution to move a text object on the pdf file, i have checked many libraries like [Docotic, pdfclown, iTextSharp, PdfSharp, PDFLibNet, Amyuni, asppdf, PDFTechLib and others] , i have found two libraries that can do this operation

1. [amyuni](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features/) its code is simple but after modifying the position i got another issue: figure color has been changed,
2. the other library is [foxitsoftware](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/sdk/dll/) and this is a sample code of how i did it.

   ```
   public static void Modify(string pdfFile)
   {
       IntPtr pdf_doc = IntPtr.Zero;
       IntPtr pdf_page = IntPtr.Zero;
       TextInfo TxtInfo = null;
       ObjectInfo ObjInfo = null;
       ArrBuf = new ArrayList();
       FPDFView.FPDF_InitLibrary(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle);
       FPDFView.FPDF_UnlockDLL("xxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
       pdf_doc = FPDFLIB.FPDFView.FPDF_LoadDocument(pdfFile, "");
       pdf_page = FPDFView.FPDF_LoadPage(pdf_doc, 0);

       IntPtr Page_Obj = FPDFEditBase.FPDFPage_GetObject(pdf_page, 0);


       FPDFEditBase.FPDFPageObj_Transform(Page_Obj, 1, 0,0, 1, 0, -40);

       ObjInfo = new ObjectInfo(pdf_doc, pdf_page, -1);
       ObjInfo.Delete(-1);


       FPDFLIB.FPDFEditBase.FPDF_FILEWRITE pFileWriter = new FPDFLIB.FPDFEditBase.FPDF_FILEWRITE();
       pFileWriter.wb = new FPDFEditBase.WriteBlock(MyDelegateFunc);
       //FPDFEditBase.FPDF_SaveDocument(pdf_doc, ref pFileWriter, 0, null, 0, null, 0, 0);
       bool flag = FPDFEditBase.FPDF_SaveDocument(pdf_doc, ref pFileWriter, 0, null, 0, null, 0, 0);
       if (flag == false)
           return;
       FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdfFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
       object[] myArr = ArrBuf.ToArray();
       for (int i = 0; i < myArr.Length; i++)
       {
           byte[] mybyte = (byte[])myArr[i];
           fs.Write(mybyte, 0, mybyte.Length);
       }

       fs.Close();
       fs.Dispose();

       FPDFLIB.FPDFView.FPDF_CloseDocument(pdf_doc);

   }
   static ArrayList ArrBuf = new ArrayList();

   public static int MyDelegateFunc(ref FPDFEditBase.FPDF_FILEWRITE pThis, IntPtr pData, UInt32 size)
   {

       byte[] byteData = new byte[size];

       System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pData, byteData, 0, (int)size);
       ArrBuf.Add(byteData);

       return 1;
   }
   ```

i hope this will be helpful for other who got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can reedit the pdf file using an specific API for .NET such iTextSharp.

Comment: thank you user1929959,
iTextSharp don't give the ability to change the y position and save to the same file

Comment: You want to have some method already made. This API contains some general functions not some particular needs, so you have to learn something about it before using it. Another method is to try to convert the pdf into an or more image files and then try to manipulate various properties of this images.